# How to create a build pipeline so that it can build multiple dependent repositories?

Tags: maven, jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, travis-ci

Currently we have two github repositories. Lets say it is repoA and repoB. We have some integration tests in repoA and some unit tests in repoB, and repoA depends on repoB.

What we want is when the build is successful along with all the tests in repoB, to start building the repoA along with the changes of repoB. This is a java project therefore I am using the POM version specified repoB to reflect those changes in repoA.

Is there a way to set this up in a CI/CD tool?

Comment: What do you mean by "repository"? A maven repository like Nexus? To me it seems that you mean "Maven project" instead of repository. What exactly are your repoA and repoB?

Comment: sorry let me be more clear, I mean by repository i meant was a github repository. repoA and repoB are two github repositories.